# Не могу подключить Word к C#

Tags: c#

При подключении Microsoft Office Word столкнулся с проблемой.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Возникает ошибка "Тип или имя пространства имен Office не существует в пространстве имен Microsoft".
Возможное решение, предлагаемое "Удалить ненужные директивы" не работает (в таком случае Word не подключится). Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, как вы ее решили?

Comment: Надо подключить библиотеку Word

Comment: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-target-office-applications-through-primary-interop-assemblies?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects#to-add-references), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24630753/12888024)